# How to calculate the time duration between two unix time stamps in php?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I have two time stamps from an API and i wanted to calculate the duration based on that times.

I have streaming which has a start date and an end date as unix time stamp as follows:

```
"startTime": 1489041394000,
"endTime": 1489041538000
```

From this times how can i calculate the duration of this video using php?

Comment: Just subtract the smallest from the largest, you now have the number of seconds. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$startTime = 1489041394000;
$endTime = 1489041538000;
$duration = $endTime - $startTime;
$durationInTimeFormat = date("H:m:s", $duration); //
$sec = intval($duration % 60);
echo $sec;
```